# how to get the Array list in server side

Tags: vb.net

I have created client and server application

i am trying to send the `Arraylist` from cilent to server 
the `Arraylist` is transfer from client but how to use that Array list in server to get the information of `ArrayList`

while i am printing the message in server side  it showing  System.collection.ArrayList

below is my code

Client Code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Client = New TcpClient("192.168.0.226", 8080)
        Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())

        detailList.Add(txtname.Text)
        detailList.Add(txtadd.Text)

        For Each i As String In detailList
            Console.WriteLine(i)
        Next

        Writer.Write(detailList)
        ' Writer.Write("</> " & txtaddress.Text & " <\>")

        MsgBox("datas send ")
        Writer.Flush()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Server Code

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim message As String
    Dim nStart As Integer
    Dim nLast As Integer

    If listener.Pending = True Then
        message = ""
        cline = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
        Dim reder As New StreamReader(cline.GetStream)
        While reder.Peek > -1
            message &= Convert.ToChar(reder.Read()).ToString
        End While

        If message.Contains("</>") Then
            nStart = InStr(message, "</>") + 10
            nLast = InStr(message, "<\>")
            message = Mid(message, nStart, nLast)
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(message)

        txtname.Text = message
        Label1.Text = message
        '   saveData()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub saveData()

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    sc.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into demo values('" + txtname.Text + "')", sc)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    msg = MsgBox("data save")

    sc.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Is "`detailList`" your `ArrayList`, or is there an ArrayList in your detailList?

Answer (score 1):

On this line in `Button1_Click`:

```
Writer.Write(detailList)
```

You're using the overloaded version of `Write` that takes an `Object`. In order to write out something meaningful for `Objects`, .NET has internally called `detailList`'s `ToString()` method. The `ToString()` method here is what's returning the string "System.Collection.ArrayList".

So, you aren't sending an actual `ArrayList` implementation to your server, but simply its string representation (the result of calling `ToString()` on it).

In order to send objects over TCP, you will need to **serialize** it first, and then **deserialize** it on the server side. You could use any number of binary, XML, JSON, etc. formatters to do it, or write your own.

Comment: i am not having idea about json or xml so how to do it

Comment: I think a simple search for "tcpclient object serialization" would return more than enough hits to get you started, if that is truly what you think you need. If you're just looking to send a comma-separated list of strings or something and manually re-create the list on the other end of the pipe, then you already have the requirements for a very simple serialization/deserialization implementation.